# Kotlin работа с датой и временем

Tags: kotlin, дата, datetime

Пытаюсь разобраться как работать с датой и временем в Kotlin
   Пока все что находил похоже на костыли, что бы добавить один день, необходимо прописать 4 строки

```
String dt = "2008-01-01";  
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(sdf.parse(dt));
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);  
dt = sdf.format(c.getTime());
```

Comment: говорите про Kotlin, а пишите на Java

Comment: Если говорим о Котлине, неплохо указывать еще среду исполнения (Android, JVM, Native, JS). Решения могут отличаться.

Comment: День добавляется в одной строке. Все остальное у вас для парсинга и форматирования даты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

может попробуете LocalDate

```
var date = LocalDate.parse("2020-04-18")
var period = Period.of(0, 0, 1)
var modifiedDate = date.plus(period)
```

тут в `period` можно указать Год, Месяц, День

есть так же `date.minus(period)`

Comment: API26+ в случае Android, JVM 1.8+. Kotlin мультиплатформенный же.

Comment: Про Android не в курсе, я ответил по котлину. я больше сервисы и библиотеки на нем пишу

Answer (score 0):

Ну а как вы хотите это сделать одной строчкой? У вас может быть много разных паттернов даты и каждый из них надо конвертировать.

Вы можете конечно использовать какие-то библиотеки, но и это не избавит вас от конвертирования даты.

Если у вас есть приложение в котором везде используется один и тот же паттерн, вы конечно можете сделать какую-то обёртку, в противном случае то что вы написали это один из верных способов решения